# how to bind the closest pre tag to an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having this html structure:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="print">Open</a>

<pre class="CodeBlock">
<ol class="linenums">
<li class="L0"><span>one</span></li>
<li class="L1"><span>two</span></li>
<li class="L2"><span>three</span></li>
</ol>
</pre>
<br /><br />
<a href="javascript:;" class="print">Open</a>

<pre class="CodeBlock">
<ol class="linenums">
<li class="L0"><span>four</span></li>
<li class="L1"><span>vfive</span></li>
<li class="L2"><span>six</span></li>
</ol>
</pre>
```

I use the anchor to open a new window with the content of the pre tag inside of it like this:

```
function nWin() {
  var w = window.open();
  var html = $(".CodeBlock").html();

  $(w.document.body).html(html);
}

$(function() {
   $(".print").click(nWin);
});
```

Clicking the second anchor outputs the text of the first pre element and it should be the second. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword to reference the element which was clicked on, and then the `next()` method to find the nearest sibling `pre` element. Try this:

```
function nWin() {
    var w = window.open();
    var html = $(this).next('.CodeBlock').html();
    $(w.document.body).html(html);
}

$(function() {
    $(".print").click(nWin);
});
```

Comment: i got a javascript error: "cannot read property 'document' of undefined and it is in this line: **$(w.document.body).html(html);**

Comment: I'd start a new question for that as it's a separate issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need get the following sibling, which can be achieved using `.next()`, in the event handler use `this` which refers to element which invoke the handler to get the sibling.

```
var html = $(this).next(".CodeBlock").html();
```

instead of

```
var html = $(".CodeBlock").html();
```